# Java Recursion and Returns

Tags: java, recursion, area

We aren't doing much recursion in my java course, but I wanted to learn about it so I wrote a little test program. The problem with the program is that after the `getLength` or `getWidth` methods are recalled by recursion, it does not use the user's input in the return statements, resulting in the `displayArea` method returning area as 0.0. If you could point out my mistake and/or a solution, that would be helpful. Below is the code:

```
package recursiontest;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class RecursionTest 
{

    static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        double length = getLength();
        double width = getWidth();
        double area = getDimensions(length, width);
        displayArea(area);
    }

    public static double getLength(){
        double length = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the rectangle's length: ");
        if(in.hasNextDouble()){
            length = in.nextDouble();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Input must be a double.");
            getLength();
        }
        return length;
    }

    public static double getWidth(){
        double width = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the rectangle's width: ");
        if(in.hasNextDouble()){
            width = in.nextDouble();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Input must be a double.");
            getWidth();
        }
        return width;
    }

    public static double getDimensions(double length, double width){
        double area = 0;
        area = length * width;
        return area;
    }

    public static void displayArea(double area){
        System.out.println("Area = "+area);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say this is a bad case for recursion as the user can cause a stack overflow by entering invalid values.

Comment: @clcto It probably is a bad case as you said, I don't know much about overflow issues. But I was just using a basic program I already wrote to understand how recursion was called, so it served its purpose. Feel free to leave and answer or a comment with a link to a more proper implementation of recursion, as I said above my code my course isn't really touching on recursion but I had wanted to learn about it, so anymore information would be appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to view my post.

Comment: the proper solution (in my opinion) would to *not* use recursion. Just a while loop that breaks when the input is valid. When ever you call a function, it pushes more information onto the stack, and when you leave the function it removes that information from the stack. Since there is some maximum size the stack can have, if you keep call the function over and over without ever returning, there will be no room to store the required information and you get a stack overflow exception. Since everytime the user enters an invalid value you call the function again, you could get that exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `getLength()`, you call recursively `getLength()`, but you don't use the result, which means that `return length` still returns 0

replace `getLength();` by

```
length = getLength();
```

(same for the width)

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to assign the new method to the first function that called it:

```
package recursiontest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecursionTest 
{

static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    double length = getLength();
    double width = getWidth();
    double area = getDimensions(length, width);
    displayArea(area);
}

public static double getLength(){
    double length = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the rectangle's length: ");
    if(in.hasNextDouble()){
        length = in.nextDouble();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Input must be a double.");
        length = getLength();
    }
    return length;
}

public static double getWidth(){
    double width = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the rectangle's width: ");
    if(in.hasNextDouble()){
        width = in.nextDouble();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Input must be a double.");
        width = getWidth();
    }
    return width;
}

public static double getDimensions(double length, double width){
    double area = 0;
    area = length * width;
    return area;
}

public static void displayArea(double area){
    System.out.println("Area = "+area);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When your `getLength()` method calls itself, it throws away the return value.  Try changing the recursive call to:

```
...
System.out.println("Input must be a double.");
length = getLength();
...
```

Same goes for getWidth().